# How to access react-router-v4 history prop from MobX store

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx

Is there any way to create an action in your MobX store, which pushes your app to a new url using react router v4, e.g. this.props.history.push...

I constantly get a history undefined error, but am unsure how to access the history from my store.

The history push called from the component itself does work though..

many thanks! (this is driving me crazy..)

Answer (score 3):

Since I stumbled across the same issue, I'll share my solution. I just put the `RouterStore` into its own file in my stores directory, then if I needed access to `history` or `location` or whatever, I would import the routing store into the store I was currently working in.

`./stores/routing.ts`

```
import { RouterStore } from 'mobx-react-router'

export default new RouterStore()
```

`./stores/other-store.ts`

```
import routing from './routing'

export class OtherStore {
  @action
  doSomething = () => {
    routing.push('/new-route')
  }
}

export default new OtherStore()
```

`./index.ts`

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'mobx-react-router'

import otherStore from './stores/other-store'
import routing from './stores/routing'

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory()

const stores = {
  otherStore,
  routing,
}

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, routing)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider {...stores}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mobx-react-router](https://github.com/alisd23/mobx-react-router) to put react-router in a mobx store and then use it by injecting it in components.

You can also pass the router store as a constructor argument to your other stores that need it. This way you have the router history instance available in your mobx store.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a simpler solution that does not require any additional libraries. 
React Router version is 5.2

Among my stores i've created a `HistoryStore.js` with the following code:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export class HistoryStore {
    history = createBrowserHistory();
}
```

Then I create an instance of it in my `contexts.js` file but you could do it right away.

```
export const history =  new HistoryStore();
```

After that you import it in your `index.js` and pass it as a `history` prop to the `Router`.

That's it. Now you could import this store into any other and use it there. When you use `useHistory` hook in your component it gets this history object, so your history in synchronized.